# can't find optimal resolution for external screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I have an external 22" screen that I'm using with my lenovo laptop. [image]

All the possible resolutions don't render the screen properley. The (16:10) leaves the screen black and the monitors shows a no signal error message. My laptop is linked to the monitor with an hdmi cable.

running:

```
xrandr --curent
```

gives the follwing output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 720, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1280x720+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   1366x768      59.97 +  48.03  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00* 
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
HDMI1 connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.88 +  59.95  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x720      60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
```

uname -a:

```
Linux IdeaPad-U330p 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The optimal resolution is always the monitor's native resolution.

Comment: I found the native resolution, have can i enter it manually? since it's not available from the system settings

Comment: Is it a VGA connection? If so you're probably in for a lot of trouble and you may need to use `xrandr` to set the correct mode. If it is a digital connection (HDMI, DVI or DP) then the problem is with the graphics drivers.

Comment: The connection between the monitor and my laptop is with hdmi.  how can i modify the graphic drivers?

Comment: Please edit and update your question with that information (HDMI), your hardware specs, especially graphics (obviously), and the exact model number of the said monitor and we'll see what can be done about it.

Comment: Also tell us the native resolution. The `xrand` tool should be able to set it.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure you might or might not need it now, but this is for anyone else having this problem. 
This worked for me. Like someone said in in the comments, im using xrandr

```
xrandr | grep maximum &
sleep 2
gtf 2560 1440 60.0 &
sleep 2
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00" 311.83  2560 2744 3024 3488  1440 1441 1444 1490  -HSync +Vsync &
sleep 2
xrandr --addmode DP1 2560x1440_60.00 &
sleep 2
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00 &
exit 0
```

Comment: could you explain this a little? How is it used?

Comment: Just copy paste it in a .sh file 
do `chmod +x <file>.sh`
and `./<file>.sh`